# WebM wrong content type on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, webm

I have a rails app on heroku which deals with video files. When I try to upload .webm files I get this message.

```
[paperclip] Content Type Spoof: Filename bird.webm (["audio/webm", "video/webm"]), content type discovered from file command: application/octet-stream. See documentation to allow this combination.
```

I know that `paperclip` uses `file` command to determine files content types so I checked this on my machine and I got:

```
$> file --mime-type bird.webm 
bird.webm: video/webm
```

I also noticed that content type is OK in tempfile in request parameters:

```
params[:file].content_type # "video/webm"
```

Is there other way to deal with this than adding `application/octet-stream` as a valid .webm mime-type?